# Agent automatically disabled

Tags: scheduled-task, ibm-domino, agent

I've an agent scheduled every day. 
Over the weekend the agent is disabled by something. 
Database is refreshed, but agent has the "no-refresh" checked.
What to investigate?

Comment: Can you give us more infos? Is that a single DB on a single server or is that on a cluster and replicated across the environment? Did you also tried to disable the designer task on the weekend, to be sure its not the designer task who caused the issue? If it runs for a weekend you might be a step closer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry....

Customer said me that agent has "no-refresh" checked.
Actually, investigating on his production server, it results unchecked.

It was a false alarm

Comment: technically my first sentence answered your question -no matter if your assumption was wrong or not- Would be nice to credit the effort and not take the credits for yourself...

Answer (score 1):

Usually I would instantly say "Designer task". But as the agent is has the no-refresh flag set, you need to investigate deeper:

After the agent has been disabled, check the properties of the agent before doing anything else. Check what the `Modified` and `Modified in this file`.

The timestamp to check is the `Modified in this file`: Write it down and open the log.nsf on the server to check, if you can find out, what happened at exact that time.

If `Modified` and `Modified in this file` do NOT match, then the change came from another database (via Designer task) or from another replica, then you can check the activity log of the database to find out who (user or server) wrote anything to the database at the time interval in question.

This investigation can be time consuming, but you most probably will find the reason.

If you find the only thing to write to the database in that period is the designer task, then this might be a bug. Then I would suggest to enable the agent in the template with the same parameters as in the database: then even when the agent is overwritten, it will be enabled nevertheless.

As scheduled agents do never run in templates, this is not a big deal.